# How to loop through anonymous object in c#

Tags: c#, foreach, anonymous-types

I have anonymous object looking like this:

```
var permissions = new
    {
        Module1 = new { view = true, delete = true },
        Module2 = new { view = true, delete = true },
    };
```

I tried with below code, but not working as expected

```
 foreach (var kp in permissions.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        var obj = kp.GetValue(Permissions, null);
        var prop = kp.Name + ",View Mode:" + obj.view ; 
    }
```

How can i display object Name and Value? Any help or input is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Anonymous object should be array or it is object graph in your case?

Comment: @MickyD expecting output is `Module1, View Mode: true`

Comment: @MickyD I can't change the `permissions` variable because it is referenced by a DLL on my project.

Comment: Whats wrong with `permissions.Module1.view`?

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work.

```
    static void Test()
    {
        var permissions = new
        {
            Module1 = new { view = false, delete = true },
            Module2 = new { view = true, delete = true },
        };

        foreach(var kp in permissions.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties)
        {
            var obj = kp.GetValue(permissions);
            var objectType = obj.GetType().GetTypeInfo();

            foreach (var item in objectType.DeclaredProperties)
            {
                var prop = kp.Name + ",view mode: " + item.GetValue(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

alter it, to get extract formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with dynamic?

```
dynamic permissions = new
    {
        Module1 = new { view = true, delete = true },
        Module2 = new { view = true, delete = true },
    };

permissions.Module1.view ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`System.Reflection`** namespace for it which contains types that retrieve information about assemblies, modules, members, parameters, and other entities in managed code by examining their metadata.

Here is how you can iterate through anonymous obj using this namespace:

```
    var permissions = new
    {
        Module1 = new { view = true, delete = true },
        Module2 = new { view = true, delete = true },
    };

    foreach(var p in permissions.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        dynamic objValue = p.GetValue(permissions, null);
        Console.WriteLine("Key {0}", ": " + p.Name); //prints obj name
        Console.WriteLine("View {0}", ": " + objValue.view); //prints 'view' parameter's value of obj 
        Console.WriteLine("Delete {0}", ": " + objValue.delete + "\n"); //prints 'delete' parameter's value of obj
    }
```

Read more about **`System.Reflection`** on [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netcore-3.1).